# GitHub pages Deployment Status Label: Abandoned

Tags: github, github-pages

Can anyone tell me what does this label is about?

```
Deployment Status Label: Abandoned
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concerned issue may arise due to the problem in the release of your website which you have deployed on Github pages. For resolving this issue you can follow the following procedure, it might help because I face the same issue a few days ago and I have done the same thing and it did work for me.

1. Try deleting the release of your website from your GitHub repository.
2. If you are deploying your website on root directory then delete the
   release folders directly.
3. And if you are deploying your website on the docs directory the delete
   the docs directory from your repository.
4. After deleting the release from the repository go to settings and then disable thee Github pages.
5. Now, generate the new release and push it on your GitHub repository, and then enable the GitHub pages again.

This will change the status of your GitHub pages from abandoned to active again.